# React/Redux - how should I store a list of objects that can be reordered with Drag and Drop?

Tags: database, reactjs, redux

I'm building an application that contains a list of cards(stored in the redux state), which user should be able to reorder with Drag and Drop.

What is the right way to store and update the order of such objects?

Comment: refer this that will help you https://codepen.io/kentwilliam/pen/xAKdj

Answer (score 0):

Use react state of the component that is a container of the cards, unless the order somehow affects other components in the app, in that case store the order in redux store as well.

On drop event if you need to sync the order with a database right away, use async action(thunk or saga) with the updated order.

For reference there is an advice from Dan Abramov for when to use react state vs redux store.
    https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287#issuecomment-175351978